# Retrieve final hidden activation layer output from sklearn's MLPClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

I would like to do some tests with neural network final hidden activation layer outputs using sklearn's `MLPClassifier` after `fit`ting the data.

for example, If I create a classifier, assuming data `X_train` with labels `y_train` and two hidden layers of sizes `(300,100)`

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(300,100))
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I would like to be able to call a function somehow to retrieve the final hidden activation layer vector of length `100` for use in additional tests.

Assuming a test set `X_test, y_test`, normal prediction would be:

```
preds = clf.predict(X_test)
```

But, I would like to do something like:

```
activation_layers_for_all_X_test = clf.get_final_activation_output(X_test)
```

Functions such as `get_weights` exist, but that would only help me on a per layer basis. Short of doing the transformation myself, is there another methodology to retrieve these final hidden layer activated outputs for the final hidden layer?

Looking at this diagram as an example:

[image]

The output I would like is the `Out Layer`, i.e. the final activated output from the final hidden layer.

Comment: Are you looking for `predict_proba`? That's the final layers activation as I understand it.

Comment: @ncfirth the `predict_proba` is the output of the `softmax` not the actual hidden activation layer output. The final hidden layer output is given to a `softmax` final layer output. Basically i want the hidden layer outputs before that point. I just realised I may not have explained this well. I will try to fix the question.

Comment: Ah ok, it looks like there's not a function in sklearn. See my answer, just coming

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, it doesn't look like there's a function to do exactly what you want in `sklearn` but you can hack the `_predict` function very easily to make it do what you want. The following code will return all activations, you can edit this to `return activations[-2]` for just the bit that you're after.

```
def get_activations(clf, X):
        hidden_layer_sizes = clf.hidden_layer_sizes
        if not hasattr(hidden_layer_sizes, "__iter__"):
            hidden_layer_sizes = [hidden_layer_sizes]
        hidden_layer_sizes = list(hidden_layer_sizes)
        layer_units = [X.shape[1]] + hidden_layer_sizes + \
            [clf.n_outputs_]
        activations = [X]
        for i in range(clf.n_layers_ - 1):
            activations.append(np.empty((X.shape[0],
                                         layer_units[i + 1])))
        clf._forward_pass(activations)
        return activations
```

Comment: This seems to be making a random np.array `np.empty` of `size =  (X.shape[0], layer_units[i+1])`, which is just based on the sizes of the activation layers. where is the summation of values and activation of summed inputs? This doesn't seem to be acting like a neuron after testing on my data. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh crap. I deleted the most important line. Updating the answer!

Comment: I was reading the `BaseMultilayerPerceptron` code in `sklearn` and this code is almost exactly what the `_predict` function does. Had a good laugh, this helped a lot, thanks @ncfirth